# Use directive to change @Input attribute

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have the following component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'box',
  [...]
})
export class BoxComponent {
  @Input() collapsable: boolean = false;
  [...]
}
```

I can use it with `<box [collapsable]="true"></box>` and it works fine. But I want to use a directive to change the attribute `collapsable` to true as in `<box box-collapsable></box>`.

I tried the following directive, but it does not work:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[box-collapsable]',
})
export class BoxCollapsableDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.el.nativeElement.attributes.collapsable = true;
  }
}
```

I do not get any error, but `collapsable` in `BoxComponent` stays on false. Is there any way to use directives to change input properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of injecting the `ElementRef` into your directive, you can inject the `BoxComponent` instance:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[box-collapsible]'
})
export class BoxCollapsibleDirective {
  constructor(private box: BoxComponent) {} // <--- inject BoxComponent instance

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.box.collapsible = true;
  }
}
```

That will give you direct access to the component's exposed properties, including its Input properties.

[Here's a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-directive-change-host-component-input-property?file=src/app/app.component.html) demonstrating this approach. (After one second, the directive changes `collapsible` from true to false.)